# deserializeUser is called after Express redirects the application

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, deserialization, passport.js

There are numerous questions on this site regarding issues with the `Passport.js` function `deserializeUser` never being called. My problem is a little more interesting - in my application, the function is being called **after** my application redirects. I provide my login code flow below, in the order in which I understand the various functions are called. I'll also try to abstract away from any unnecessary details.

In my application, `Passport.js` has been configured with a `LocalStrategy`.

```js
// Configuring passport.js
passport.use(new LocalStrategy((username, password, done) => {
  console.log("Inside Passport's Local Strategy callback...");

  // Search for the user in the database
  db.query("SELECT * FROM user;", async (err, result, fields) => {
    if (err) { // Handle the error, abstracted away }
    else {
      // Search for user in database
      for (let i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
        if (username == result[i].username) { // If the credentials are correct
          // Asynchronously check the hash in the database that represents the password
          const bcryptresult = await bcrypt.compare(password, result[i].password_hash);
          const accessresult = await bcrypt.compare(process.env.ACCESS2, result[i].access_hash);
          if (bcryptresult) {
            // Password was correct
            console.log("Username and password match for " + result[i].username + "!");
            // Construct and return the user object
            const user = { // Construct the user object (including id field), abstracted away };
            return done(null, user);
          }
          else { // Password is incorrect, handle this, abstracted away }
        }
      }
      return done(null, false, {message: "Invalid username or password."}); // User not found
    }
  });
}));
```

`serializeUser` and `deserializeUser` are constructed as follows. It seems that `deserializeUser` is not being called at the right time - in particular, **note the** `console.log()` **statement at the very top of the** `deserializeUser` **function.**

```js
passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
  console.log("Serializing the user " + user.username + " and storing their ID to the session file storage...");
  return done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser((id, done) => {
  console.log("Attempting to deserialize user with ID " + id + "...");
  db.query("SELECT * FROM user;", async (err, result, fields) => {
    if (err) { // Handle the database error, abstracted away }
    else {
      for (let i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
        if (id == result[i].id) {
          const accessresult = await bcrypt.compare(process.env.ACCESS2, result[i].access_hash);
          const user = { // Construct the user object, abstracted away };
          console.log(`Deserialization was a success. User ${result[i].username} has been found.`);
          return done(err, user);
        }
      }
      // If we get down here, then the user was somehow not found.
      console.log("Deserialize user failed, user was somehow not found.");
    }
  });
});
```

The login form on my website contains a username and a password field. Here is the route that handles `GET`ting this page.

```js
app.get('/login', (req, res) => {
  console.log("Flash messages below.");
  console.log(req.session.flash);
  if (req.isAuthenticated()) res.redirect('/');
  else {
    console.log("Login route requested on " + now() + "...");
    res.render('login.html');
  }
});
```

The login form is posted to this handler:

```js
app.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local',
  {
    successRedirect: '/profile',
    successFlash: "Logged in successfully!",
    failureRedirect: '/login#main-content',
    failureFlash: "Failed to log in."
  }
));
```

The route handler for the `/profile` route is as follows.

```js
app.get('/profile', (req, res) => {
  if (req.isAuthenticated()) { // Load the profile page, abstracted away }
  else {
    console.log(req.user ? "\nCurent user: " + req.user : "\nRequest for profile is not authenticated!")
    req.flash('access', "You need to be logged in to access your profile!");
    res.redirect('/login');
  }
});
```

Finally, here is the handler for my application's homepage.

```js
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  console.log("\nHome page requested on " + now() + "...");
  console.log(req.isAuthenticated() ? "Logged-in request for homepage." : "Logged-out request for homepage.");
  console.log(req.user);
  console.log("Requesting session ID: " + req.sessionID + "\n");
  res.render('index.html');
});
```

Observe the `console.log()` snippets in the code above. Below is the output starting from when a user posts the login form to my website. (Excuse the terrible colouring, it's from a Docker container!)

```
main_website | Inside Passport's Local Strategy callback...
main_website | Username and password match for user2!
main_website | Serializing the user user2 and storing their ID to the session file storage...
main_website | 
main_website | Request for profile is not authenticated!
main_website | Attempting to deserialize user with ID 2...
main_website | Deserialization was a success. User user2 has been found.
main_website | Flash messages below.
main_website | { success: [ 'Logged in successfully!' ] }
main_website | 
main_website | Home page requested on 2/11/2020, 00:22:58...
main_website | Logged-out request for homepage.
main_website | undefined
main_website | Requesting session ID: 85a5fd86-57a2-4957-a1e0-dc6cde6a501b
```

Based on the console output, it appears that the flow of functions is as follows:

1. The form is posted to the login `POST` route, which calls `passport.authenticate()`.
2. `passport.authenticate()` then calls the `LocalStrategy` callback, which searches for the user in the database. Here, the search is successful, and the user is found.
3. `serializeUser` is then called, after which, **the application redirects to the profile page** before calling the `deserializeUser` function (which again succeeds).
4. On the profile page, the request is **not** authenticated (since the profile was requested before deserialisation occurred), and so we redirect to the login page.
5. In the login page, the flash message for successful login has been stored, which indicates that the login was supposedly successful.
6. Since the request for the login page was supposedly authenticated, the application then redirects to the homepage, where based on the console logs, the request for the homepage here was **not** authenticated! This is confirmed by the `undefined` `req.user` object on the next line.

This same code is currently in a live, production deployment of my website (without excessive `console.log()` statements) that is working without a hitch, but for some reason, when I ran this on my computer in a container for development, it's not working.

**What is happening here?**